# Flatten the mongodb string array root level?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

this is my document format

```
[
    {
        "name" : "test1",
        "other_name" : "TEST1_1",
        "values" : ["11", "12", "13", "14"]
    },
    {
        "name" : "test2",
        "other_name" : "TEST2_1",
        "values" : ["21", "22", "23", "24"]
    },
    {
        "name" : "test3",
        "other_name" : "TEST3_1",
        "values" : ["31", "32", "13", "14"]
    },
    {
        "name" : "test1",
        "other_name" : "TEST4_1",
        "values" : ["41", "42", "43", "44"]
    },

]
```

now I want to convert this document to my desired format as

```
[
    {
        "name" : "test1",
        "other_name" : "TEST1_1",
        "values" : "11"
    },
    {
        "name" : "test1",
        "other_name" : "TEST1_1",
        "values" : "12"
    },
    {
        "name" : "test1",
        "other_name" : "TEST1_1",
        "values" : "13"
    },
    {
        "name" : "test1",
        "other_name" : "TEST1_1",
        "values" : "14"
    },
    {
        "name" : "test2",
        "other_name" : "TEST2_1",
        "values" : ["21"]
    },
    {
        "name" : "test2",
        "other_name" : "TEST2_1",
        "values" : ["22"]
    },
    {
        "name" : "test2",
        "other_name" : "TEST2_1",
        "values" : ["23"]
    },
    {
        "name" : "test2",
        "other_name" : "TEST2_1",
        "values" : ["24"]
    },
    {
        "name" : "test1",
        "other_name" : "TEST4_1",
        "values" : ["41"]
    },    
    {
        "name" : "test1",
        "other_name" : "TEST4_1",
        "values" : ["42"]
    },    
    {
        "name" : "test1",
        "other_name" : "TEST4_1",
        "values" : ["43"]
    },    
    {
        "name" : "test1",
        "other_name" : "TEST4_1",
        "values" : ["44"]
    },    

]
```

I've tried few options with `$unwind`, `$addToRoot` but nothing seems working out.

Can you please help me write the query for this.
I'm using python with mongodb.

Comment: A simple `$unwind` should work - it creates a document for each string in values array, db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: '$values'}]) , What's going wrong if you try that ?